# How to click on search icon using vba

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I want to click on search icon, shown below

[image: icon]

I tried by passing `id` of the node but no success.

Here is html code for the reference:

```htm
<a id="ctl00_CPHMainSearch_hypOpenProjectPopup" href="javascript:void(window.open('ProjectPopUp.aspx?ctl00_CPHMainSearch_AutoCompPR_SearchTxt=1&amp;ctl00_CPHMainSearch_AutoCompPR_IDValue=2&amp;ViewPopMode=ProjectSearch', 'ProjectPopUpaspx', 'scrollbars=yes,width=750,height=600,top=40,left=200,resizable=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no'));"><img style="border-width: 0px;" alt="" src="../Images/popup.gif"></a>
```

I have tried some codes but no luck:-

```
Dim ProjectSearch As Object
```

Set ProjectSearch = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_CPHMainSearch_hypOpenProjectPopup")
ProjectSearch.Click

but it showing error OBJECT Required

Here is part of code:-

```
Sub code()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
User_Name = Environ$("UserName")

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Silent = True
IE.navigate "url"
IE.Visible = True

Dim ProjectSearch As Object
Set ProjectSearch = 
HtmlDoc.getElementById("ctl00_CPHMainSearch_hypOpenProjectPopup")
ProjectSearch.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: The question should be [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit the question, add VBA code you are using with proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), including URL. If that URL is inaccessible via internet, then post the entire webpage HTML content.

Comment: hi @omegastripes sorry but can't upload url or whole html content because it is a company property and against the company policy. i have provided the all html code for that search ,

Comment: what about VBA code you have?

Comment: Hi @omegastripes i have added the code i tried for reference

Comment: Could you post the entire code, including `IE` variable assignment, navigating, etc. And also proper format the code. Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Hi @omegastripes I have added the code part, sorry but can't post whole code.

Comment: 1) Check if `ctl00_CPHMainSearch_hypOpenProjectPopup` node located in the same document you are working with, but not in frame. If it is in a frame, you should get the reference to the frame's document. 2) `href` attribute in HTML snippet contains the value `javascript:void(window.open('ProjectPopUp.aspx?...`, as you can see, that just JS code, which is executed onclick event. You may try run it directly from VBA like `HtmlDoc.parentWindow.execScript "window.open('ProjectPopUp.aspx?..."` or 3) even navigate that URL `ProjectPopUp.aspx?...`.